# Why is cmd output not redirecting to nul in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, silent, output-redirect

Am writing a batch script to detect if java is installed globally on a pc.
am using:

```
java -version>nul
if not %errorlevel%==0 ( echo script requires java)
```

Also tried using `cmd /c java -version>nul`.

Script works fine, but console is outputting the java version when java is present and

`'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

when java is not present. I am trying to quash this output, and do detection silently. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 2> in command

```
java -version 2> nul
```

Comment: 2 is STDERR that we are trying to pipe. Can read more for redirection operator there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)